# Ambigious Match exception was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
     For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim due_date As Object
            Dim calc As TimeSpan
            due_date = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()
**error** ---->>>calc = Today.Subtract(due_date)<<<--------**error**
            MessageBox.Show(calc.ToString)
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "delete from periodicals where student_id= '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i))
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
```

I am trying to subtract the date today and due date in datagridview and will be shown via messagebox. I dont have any idea on how to fix this. Suggestion please

Comment: Please show how you are constructing the DataGridView, so I can recreate the problem.

Comment: im afraid to say but that is my whole code for deleting the borrower's info and computing the number of days,

Comment: You would like to cast/parse the `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()` to `datetime` (when assigning it to 'Dim due_date As DateTime' as suggested by @hawkeye)

Comment: it says Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Comment: the errors is highlighting the  "due_date=DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()"

Comment: That seems to mean that the data returned to due_date from the datagridview is null - have you checked that the value stored in due_date isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

The "Ambiguous Match" error is probably because due_date is instantiated As Object. The subtract function doesn't know what data type to subtract from.

Maybe try:

```
Dim due_date As DateTime
```

Hope that works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

```
     Dim due As Date
    Dim calc As TimeSpan
    Dim d1 As Date

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            d1 = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")
            due = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()
            calc = d1.Subtract(due)
            Dim fine As Integer = calc.Days * 20
            If MessageBox.Show("Your Penalty is:₱" & fine & "" + vbNewLine + " Do you want to remove this as paid ?", "Informed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "delete from periodicals where student_id= '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "'"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
                SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
                SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
```

Thanks for your suggestion finally it worked the way i wanted it to be.